# Correcting imported animation to avoid hand going through the face of character

Tags: unity, animation, blender

I've imported an animation from Mixamo called standing draw bow.
When I use it with my character in Unity the hand goes through the face of my character.

Is there a way to move hand a little outside the face of the character using Blender or Unity?  Or am I required to make up the animation myself?

I tried modifying parameters Mixamo offers but doesn't resolve the problem.

I actually tryed to solve the problem with IK by adding a Multi-Parent constraint ( cause i didn't manage to have multi-postion constraint to work ) and tried to move lowerarm_r Bone a little bit off the face of the character but it only did force the bow to stay in the position and rotation of the "Target" while being buggy in certain keyframes. my aim is to force that bone to not rotate more than certain degree to not go through the face while executing the animation. I believe the problem is coming from the fact that animation is made for normal head character not big head ones.

Comment: Have you tried using IK (inverse kinematics) for this? It's often used to apply adjustments to foot or hand positions after an animation update.

Comment: @DMGregory i believe that may solve my problem. i'm still new to IK, but i figured if IK can let me retarget a joint without impacting the animation of other bones then problem would be solved :D

Comment: IK doesn't solve my problem unfortunately.  i guess i'll have to change the joint rotation in the every keyframe animation.

Comment: Can you show us how you've tried to use IK to solve the problem? "I haven't managed to solve the problem with IK yet" is different from "No IK solution could possibly work"

Comment: my bad. I actually added a Multi-Parent constraint ( cause i didn't manage to have multi-postion constraint to work ) and tried to move lowerarm_r Bone a little bit off the face of the character but it only did force the bow to stay in the position and rotation of the "Target" while being buggy in certain keyframes. my aim is to force that bone to not rotate more than certain degree to not go through the face while executing the animation. I believe the problem is coming from the fact that animation is made for normal head character not big head ones.

Comment: Looks like those details should be added to your question, so folks can provide answers that solve that specific circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that putting that animation (since other animations works well) in another animation layer and lowering the weight of the animation layer force the hand to not rotating too much and go through the character face.

edit: i actually found out that you can also lower the weight of only the bones that rotates too much by reassigning the mesh's bonesWeight using a C# script if you want it to be made for a short time or if you have problem with your animations you can configure bones rotation limits by configuring the avatar of your character.